# Counter isn't incremented when using the useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0);


  const handleAsyncUpdate = async () => {
    setCount1(count1 + 2);
    setCount1(count1 + 1);
  };

  const handleSyncUpdate = () => {
    setCount1(count1 + 2);
    setCount1(count1 + 1);
  };

  console.log("render", count1);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{count1}</h2>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAsyncUpdate}>
        Click for async update
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSyncUpdate}>
        Click for sync update
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When i click on the second button, i expect the `<h2>{count1}</h2>` to render `3` (0 + 1 + 2), but instead it renders `1`.

If i switch `setCount1(count1 + 1);` to `setCount1(count => count + 1);` then it works properly, but why?

Comment: `setState` call async, in your case you have race conditions between `setCount1(count1 + 2)` and `setCount1(count1 + 1);` excluding previous state. If you switch to `setCount1(count => count + 1);` you start to consider the previous state value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about the way `useState` (or even `this.setState` if you were using classes) work. These operations are always asynchronous, React schedules these changes according to what it deems a priority or not.

By placing `async` on a function you are not saying that it's suddenly asynchronous, instead, you're saying it returns a `Promise`.

In terms of the way React works, this doesn't change anything. So effectively your `handleSyncUpdate` and `handleAsyncUpdate` are basically the same for React, they both trigger async operations (changing state).

`setCount1(count => count + 1)` - Using this, you are literally using the last state value to update, guaranteeing that the new value will be the last one + 1.

`setCount1(count1 + 1)` - In this case you are using a value that is mutated by another `setState` between the moment this `setState` is called and the moment React performs an update.

I hope this helps

Comment: Ahh ok i think i understand!
So in my case, i made 2 calls: `setCount1(count1 + 1)` and `setCount1(count1 + 2)`. But since they are executed asynchronously, the value of `count1` as far as each call is concerned is `0`? (since they are not aware of each other)

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, yes! When both `setState` are called, `count1` is `0`.